# AS3 loading external swf on button click

Tags: actionscript-3, button, flash

In AS3 (Flash), I want an external swf-file to load when I click a specific menu button. I also want the swf to disappear when I click another button, so that another swf can load. This code shows my swf, but it just "loops". And also it covers my menu (on the top of the page) so I can't click anywhere. What could I change in the code to fix this?

```
var loader_mc : Loader = new  Loader();
   addChild(loader_mc);

bilder_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,  buttonClick)
function  buttonClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     try{
loader_mc.unloadAndStop();
} catch(e:Error) {
}
      var urlRequest : URLRequest = new  URLRequest("flickr.swf");
      loader_mc.load(urlRequest);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by" it just loops" ? if the loaded swf is loping you will need a stop(); in there

Comment: I've tried with stop(); and nothing happens. Where should I put it?

Comment: in your child swf, wherever you need it to stop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change `loader_mc`'s X and Y so that the loaded SWF does not cover your menu.
2. You could do better with reinitializing that `loader_mc` to load another SWF, that is, create a `new Loader()`, `removeChild()` the old loader, `addChild()` the new one, then load.

Comment: `loader)mc.y=60;` and `removeChild(loader_mc); loader_mc.content.unloadAndStop(); loader_mc=new Loader(); addChild(loader_mc);`